# Apply changes dynamically when OpenShift template is modified (and applied)

Tags: openshift, s2i

I defined a template (let's call it `template.yaml`) with a service, deploymentconfig, buildconfig and imagestream, applied it with `oc apply -f template.yaml` and ran `oc new-app app-name` to create new app from the template. What the app basically does is to build a Node.js application with S2I, write it to a new ImageStream and deploy it to a pod with the necessary service exposed.

Now I've decided to make some changes to the template and have applied it on OpenShift. How do I go about ensuring that all resources in the said template also get reconfigured without having to delete all resources associated with that template and recreating it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command turned out to be:

```
$ oc apply -f template_modified.yaml 
$ oc process -f template_modified.yaml | oc replace -f -
```

That worked for me on OpenShift 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `template` is only used to create the related resource first time. Even though you modify the `template`, it's not associated with created resources. So you should recreate or modify each resource that is modified.

But you can modify simply all resources created by `template` using the following cmd.

```
# oc apply -f template_modified.yaml | oc replace -f -
```

I hope it help you